# How to generate map with geopandas and OpenStreetMaps in high resolution?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, contextily

I would like to generate a high resolution maps in python using following:

```
catnetDATA = os.path.join('data', 'CATNET10k.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(catnetDATA)

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'} 
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
geo_df.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename='data.shp')

geo_df = geo_df.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

In this code:

```
ax = geo_df.plot(column='WILDFIRE',figsize=(20,20), alpha=1, legend=True, cmap='YlOrRd', scheme='user_defined',
legend_kwds={'title': "Wildfire risk"}, classification_kwds={'bins':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
ax.set_axis_off()
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs='epsg:4326', source=ctx.sources.OSM_A)
```

the result looks almost good. Only the OSM map resolution is too low:
[map1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I1lf.jpg)

after adding zoom=3 to function below:

```
ctx.add_basemap(ax, zoom=3, crs='epsg:4326', source=ctx.sources.OSM_A)
```

[map2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX1jR.png)

In map2 it looks bad. The resolution has not increased.
How to generate map with geopandas and OpenStreetMaps in high resolution?

Comment: what happens for a larger `zoom`?

Comment: Answer is in map2

Comment: I meant larger than 3. 5 6..